# Restore keyboard that was used in specific EditText some time ago

Tags: android, sdk, keyboard, android-input-method, input-language

In my application, I have the TextEdit for which I want to control virtual keyboard language ([input method subtype](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodSubtype.html)). As far as I know, it is impossible to force the virtual keyboard to show up with the specific language selected or even get current keyboard language [reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156642/detect-keyboard-ime-language-on-android).

But I was thinking about such solution when the application at some point stores some unique id of the current keyboard (without knowing which input language is currently used) and then at some point restores this keyboard using previously stored id. Of course, I do not want to create [system application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#setCurrentInputMethodSubtype(android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSubtype)) or to implement [my own keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305084/how-do-i-change-the-input-method-programatically)

Is such API exists in Android SDK?